# iPhone Help: Odd Memory Leak In CoreLocation Framework

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, gps, core-location

I've been working to iron out memory leaks in my program and I'm down to a few stragglers. The  strange thing is that they're coming from when I use CoreLocation to get a gps location. The code is properly returning the location, but it's leaking all over the place: CFHTTPMessage, CFURLConnection, CFURLRequest, CFURLResponse, GeneralBlock-16,-32,-48, HTTPRequest, etc... Could anyone please guide me how to fix this?

Initialization of MyCLController

```
locationController = [[MyCLController alloc] init];
locationController.delegate = self;
[locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Do some things and get a call back through the delegate:

```
[locationController release];
```

MyCLController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol MyCLControllerDelegate 
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;
@end
@interface MyCLController : NSObject  {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    id delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

MyCLController.m:

```
#import "MyCLController.h"
@implementation MyCLController
@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self.delegate locationError:error];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to release the LocationManager. Make sure that you set its delegate to NULL prior to releasing. And also, it's not a good idea to just return the first result. Make sure horizontal accuracy is not < 0 and is also below some threshold, like 5000 meters. And to make it more robust, you might want to add a timer to make it stop after a given amount of time, if it couldn't find your location accurately enough.

Answer (score 1):

you never release `locationController`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's actually not where the leak is coming from, I forgot to post my dealloc method.  The leak happens exactly when I call startUpdatingLocation.

    [locationController release];